# Robertson's system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have just one problem concerning this system of ODE's. The plot shows us the concentrations of A, B and C. Doesn't the mass of the system change? When looking at the graph the green curve goes up and then down (very fast) without the other two substances changing in concentration at all. I feel I have misunderstood something. Basically I am having a problem understanding the plot.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the system of ODE's?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I have updated the question

Comment: Which variables correspond to which colours?  What are the initial conditions?

Comment: You can search "Robertson" and find to take you to the part where they talk about it  here : http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ordinary-differential-equations.html and read about the IV and the ODE problem. it is under the "Differential-Algebraic Equations" title

Answer (score 1):

As it says in that web page, $y_2$ was multiplied by $10^{4}$ to make it visible when plotting the solution.  The green bump corresponds to this scaled $y_2$; its effect on $y_1$ and $y_3$ is too small to be visible.